# Incorrect count of favorites displayed on day, week, month summary

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, bookmarks

The information displayed in the quick summary area (when you mouse-over your name at the top bar, what is it called?) is showing wrong number of favorites for me.

This is what I am seeing:

[image: Summary]

But I am positive that I did not add 7 favorite items today or this week. I had added two questions to favorite today, and the rest have been in my favorites before that.

I do not have a way to confirm this with fact as the favorites tab does not provide you with information about when a question was favorited. But I sorted them by "added" and can confirm that the first 7 of them were not added today.

Comment: Maybe 7 of your favorites got deleted today?

Comment: @juergend: In that case does it also mean 7 of my favorites got deleted in this week and month?

Comment: Today is in this week and this month.

Comment: @juergend makes sense, is there an option available to see deleted favorite questions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should hover the numbers in the tab.

For me, the title attribute states `13 : 13 new answers or comments on your favorites this month`

So the number does not represent the number of favorite questions added but the number of activities on favorite questions.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!